# Unknown command: 'clearsessions'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.5.1, and according to django documentation cleanup is deprecated in this django version and cleansessions should be used.
When I try using cleansessions it states unknown command. And when I type **djando-admin.py help**. I don't get it listed in the commands, I instead get cleanup listed.
And on using **django-admin.py cleanup**, I get the following error -

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not
>   configured. You must either define the environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
>   settings.

Any Idea what is causing so.

Answer (score 7):

You should always use `manage.py` rather than `django-admin.py` to run any commands that depend on an existing project, as that sets up DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for you.

Comment: now It seems it works, but it doesn't give any output. Is this the normal behavior of the clearsessions command ??